# use formatter to consume topic `__offset_consumers` then output nothing in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

my kafka version is 2.4.1, it is wired that I use formatter to output topic '__consumer_offsets' message that the console output nothing while don't use formatter can output message, here is my shell command

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic __consumer_offsets --formatter 'kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager$OffsetsMessageFormatter' --from-beginning
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 types of records in this topics:

- Offsets records: These contain offsets committed by groups. They are printed using the `kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager$OffsetsMessageFormatter` formatter
- GroupMetadata records: These contain metadata (state and members) of groups. They are printed using the `kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager$GroupMetadataMessageFormatter` formatter

Your command is correct. It's possible you only have GroupMetadata records hence using the Offsets formatter does not print anything.

Comment: yes, there are only GroupMetaData records, why it doesn't have any Offsets records?(I have used command ``./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic topic-create`` to consume records and succeed)

Comment: Well, I find it is necessary for adding ``enable.auto.commit=true
auto.commit.interval.ms=100`` to consumer.properties, however there are still no Offsets records

Comment: If you don't specify `--group` when using `kafka-console-consumer.sh`, it disables auto commit (https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/ConsoleConsumer.scala#L374-L380). This is why you don't get Offsets records.